# Tomcat 7 and Eclipse integration getting error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I had installed Tomcat7 from Ubuntu's repository but when I added Tomcat7 into Eclipse, this dialog indicates something wrong with Tomcat Server Configuration at `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf.`

How should I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: until now, not yet :(