# Cannot start tomcat after installing a private instance

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, tomcat7

Ok, now I've spend enough time configuring Tomcat properly on my Ubuntu 12.04 OS, and I'm already fed-up, given that it's already 2:00 am.

First I installed tomcat7 as described in this question - [How should I install Apache Tomcat 7 for use with Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/q/310767/159439).

Then I thought I would install a private instance of tomcat as described in an answer to the linked question. So, I uninstalled `tomcat7` using the process described in this question - https://askubuntu.com/q/313070/159439

And now, I installed a private instance using:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-user
sudo tomcat7-instance-create ~/my-tomcat-instance
```

Now, when I go to start the tomcat, it's not starting. Since it is not installed as a service, so I of course cannot start it as a service. But, I can't even start it using the `startup.sh` file. I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7$ bin/startup.sh

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr

Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
bin/catalina.sh: 389: bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

Now what's the problem here. I understand that earlier tomcat was not starting as it was installed as a service. So, I've to use - `service tomcat7 start`, to start it. But now, it's not installed as a service. So, how am I supposed to start it?

---

I'm facing another issue of configuring the newly installed tomcat in eclipse. It's showing me the same error as in this question - [Tomcat 7 and Eclipse integration getting error](https://askubuntu.com/q/310321/159439) when I add the server. I'm using Eclipse Juno. Installed it by downloading a `.tar.gz` file.

Kindly help me out of here. I've been stuck with it for the last 5 hours.

Comment: When you created the "New Server Runtime Environment" in Eclipse, what directory did you enter as the "Tomcat installation directory"?

Comment: `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### From the command line

To run your private instance of Tomcat from the command line, you need to run the `startup.sh` script within the private instance directory rather than the one in `/usr/share/tomcat7`. So, in your case, you need to run:

```
~/my-tomcat-instance/bin/startup.sh
```

This should work out-of-the-box.

### From Eclipse

To run from Eclipse you should also create your Server Runtime Environment using your `~/my-tomcat-instance/` directory instead of `/usr/share/tomcat7/`.

However, getting this working is far harder than it should be. This is partly because Eclipse is a bit buggy, and partly because Eclipse doesn't distinguish between `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME`.

**Missing files**

It turns out that the `tomcat7-instance-create` script does not set up everything that Eclipse needs. This was reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat6/+bug/297675) that appears to have been fixed at some point for Tomcat 6, but for whatever reason the patch is not in the `tomcat7-user` package. I've raised a new [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1195189) in the hope this will get fixed, but in the meantime, you need to run the following commands:

```
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/lib ~/my-tomcat-instance/lib
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar ~/my-tomcat-instance/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Then you need to grab a copy of `catalina.policy` which is not distributed as part of the `tomcat7-user` package and put it in the `conf/` directory in your instance. You can get it from the [code repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/tomcat7/precise/files) for the `tomcat7` package:

```
curl http://bazaar.launchpad.net/\~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/tomcat7/precise/view/head:/conf/catalina.policy > ~/my-test-tomcat7-instance/conf/catalina.policy
```

**New server bug**

Whilst testing this, I also ran into another bug, which I solved by deleting these files:

```
{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
```

as per the accepted answer on [Eclipse add Tomcat 7 blank server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name). Obviously, only do this step if you need to.

---

See also [Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) 'Cannot create a server using the selected type' in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423593/eclipse-4-2-juno-cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-in-tomcat-7) for getting this working using the `tomcat7` package.

Comment: Thank you so much @David. Everything's working fine now. Such a great explanation you have written. Thanks again :)

Comment: I just wanted to say that this answer worked great for me although I had to add one more symbolic link: ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar ~/my-tomcat-instance/bin/tomcat-juli.jar Without it, my server wouldn't start in Eclipse. I'm using Kepler and Java 7.